# GET-запрос из html в скрипт Python на Ubuntu

Tags: python, html, cgi

Full backup. Необходимо, чтобы **название БД можно было ввести из веб-формы(простое поле и кнопка Submit)**, а скрипт принял этот get запрос и вставил его на место переменной DB_NAME. Так же есть ошибка, если ввести неправильное название БД, которой не существует, то файл всё равно создаётся. Такого быть не должно.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import time
import pipes
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
searchterm = form.getvalue('')
DB_HOST = 'localhost'
DB_USER = 'root'
DB_USER_PASSWORD = 'pass'
print('Ваш пользователь: ' + DB_USER)
print("Добро пожаловать!")
print("Введите название вашей базы данных:", end=" ")
DB_NAME = input()
BACKUP_PATH = '/home/admin/db_backups'
try:
    connect = "mysql" + "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '"+DB_NAME+"';"
except:
    print("Error!")

DATETIME = time.strftime('%a.%d.%m.%y-%X')
TODAYBACKUPPATH = BACKUP_PATH + '/' + DATETIME

try:
    os.stat(TODAYBACKUPPATH)
except:
    os.mkdir(TODAYBACKUPPATH)

    print ("Начался процесс резервного копирования! ")
# Резервное копирование, создание бэкапа.
    dumpmysql_cli = "mysqldump -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + DB_USER_PASSWORD + " " + DB_NAME + " > " + pipes.quote(
        TODAYBACKUPPATH) + "/" + DB_NAME + ".sql"
    os.system(dumpmysql_cli)
    print("Резервное копирование завершено!")
    gzipcmd = "gzip " + pipes.quote(TODAYBACKUPPATH) + "/" + DB_NAME + ".sql"
    os.system(gzipcmd)
    print("")
    print("Ваша база была сохранена по адресу: '" + TODAYBACKUPPATH + "'directory")
```

Comment: В скрипте запускается команда, в которую просто вставляется значение DB_NAME, которое предполагается получать через веб-интерфейс. Это очень небезопасно, злоумышленник может ввести значение, которое приведёт к формированию совсем не такой команды, как вы ожидаете. Давайте для простоты рассмотрим такой пример. Допустим, нужно вывести информацию о файле командой ls -l, и в коде есть строка для этого: os.system("ls -l " + name), при этом если злоумышленник сможет обеспечить для переменной name значение "; cat /etc/passwd", тогда выполнятся две команды, и вторая — совсем не та, что предполагалась.

Comment: @askh Я понимаю, это небезопасно. Но! Это выполняется локально, обязательно использование  MySQL и наличие веб-формы для авторизации. Я сделаю это безопасно, когда пойму как принимать GET запрос в скрипт.

Comment: Для того, чтобы принимать веб-запросы, нужен веб-сервер. Например, Apache или Nginx, также веб-сервер может быть реализован на самом Python (для этого есть соответствующая библиотека). Какой вариант вы предполагаете использовать?

Comment: Есть Apache2 на котором уже висит Nextcloud и MariaDB. Он настроен и полностью функционирует